# Tuleap server installation on Centos

Tags: tuleap

I'm trying to install Tuleap server on CentOS. i have followed below link

http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html

when i was executing this command 
yum install -y tuleap-all tuleap-plugin-git-gitolite3

i got below  error can anyone help on this.

Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-bcmath
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-opcache
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-fpm
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-process
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-soap
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-mysqlnd
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-pear
Error: Package: tuleap-plugin-tracker-5.1661-9.16.99.9_1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-imap
Error: mysql55w-libs conflicts with mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-mbstring
Error: Package: tuleap-plugin-git-gitolite3-4.453-9.16.99.9_1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-git29-git
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-pecl-jsonc
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-xml
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-cli
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-gd
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-pdo
Error: Package: tuleap-plugin-ldap-3.165-9.16.99.9_1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-ldap
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64
Error: Package: tuleap-9.16.99.9-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: rh-php56-php-intl
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: `Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64`. Tuleap is trying to install php 5.6 but you already have php 5.3.3 installed.

Comment: i have removed php 5.3.3 but i m getting same error.

Comment: Uninstall `php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_65`. Not sure if that will break anything else though.